# Multi-select pill overflow according to width instead of count

Tags: angular, design-patterns, components

We're trying to implement pills into our multi-select box and once it overflows the box, have it show '...X more'.

Currently we're looking to use [Ant Design's multi-selection box.](https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en)

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pxfu7)

What Ant Design's multi-selection does is allow you to determine the count before it shows the '...X more' text. However this requires huge flexibility on design and coding because we would have to set a value for each instance depending on space available.

So to combat this, we're looking to implement one that shows '...X more' if the next pill will overflow the container.

Thoughts on if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had this exact same problem, scoured the internet in hopes to find a solution, and here's what I came up with in the end.

A few notes:
You will need to find out your limiting width, padding around the actual text of the chip/space between each chip, and adjust the 'paddingAddition' accordingly. The goal of this is to get the width of the text (the unknown), and then add in the knowns (padding/space between chips/margins around container/etc.) to get a final chip count based on the width.

also, if you plan to resize you would have to tie in a listener for window resizing and adapt your pixelLimit/recall chip count accordingly.

```
getChipCount() {
    const pixelLimit = 200; // width available in px for your container
    const paddingAddition = 8; // padding(4) left/right on each chip
    let chipCount = 0;
    let currentSizeTotal = 16; //(margin(8) left+right initial value)
    for(const chip of this.chipData) {
      const size = (paddingAddition + this.gitChipWidth(chip));
      if((currentSizeTotal + size) <= pixelLimit ) {
        chipCount++;
        currentSizeTotal += size;
      }
      else {
        return chipCount ;
      }
    }
    return chipCount;
  }


// you can pass in a font or use a default.
// note: I defined canvas in my file to allow for re-use for performance 
getTextWidth(text, font = 'normal 12px montserrat') {
    // re-use canvas object for better performance
    const context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = font;
    const metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
  }
```